# combine and newtheorem

Tags: theorems, combine

I'm having trouble marrying `combine` and `amsthm` packages.

Minimal example:

### `compilation.tex`

```
\documentclass[colclass=amsart]{combine}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{combine}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\begin{papers}

\coltoctitle{Paper title}
\coltocauthor{Paper author}
\import{paper1}

\end{papers}

\end{document}
```

### `paper1.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Theorem statement
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

When I try to process it like that:

```
> pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction nonstopmode compilation.tex
```

...I get the following:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [colclass=amsart].

(./compilation.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) (./compilation.toc)
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] (./paper1.tex
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.5 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on compilation.log.
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug with the `combine` package as the following illustrates. In case of bugs you should email the package author directly. The contact info is [in the `combine` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/combine).

```
%\documentclass[colclass=amsart]{combine}% Missing \endcsname inserted.
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}% Works

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        Theorem statement
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

You might want to consider using the `standalone` package, depending on what you want to achieve.